# Service gets killed

Tags: android, service

I had created one service and started in onCreate() of launcher activity.But when i am comming out of application and then manually changes the time or date,service automatically gets stop and onDestroy() method of service also not called.why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

As i have knowledge,

This will happened in the case exception.thats why you dont get onDestroy callback.